# Search and Print in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have a log file on UNIX server and I am trying to search for single pattern and print multiple strings from the log.

For Example log is as follows:

```
2016-01-01 10:10:10.234 SEND <Msg><Name>XYZ</Name><ID>1231231</ID></Msg>
2016-01-01 10:10:10.333 RECIEVE <Msg><Name>XYZ</Name><ID>1231231</ID></Msg> 
2016-01-01 10:10:11.434 SEND <Msg><Name>ABC</Name><ID>2231231</ID></Msg>
2016-01-01 10:10:11.533 RECIEVE <Msg><Name>ABC</Name><ID>2231231</ID></Msg>
```

I want to search for 'SEND' and print the output as follows:

```
10:10:10 1231231
10:10:11 2231231
```

Thanx in Advance

Comment: What language you are using? Maybe on Unix StackExchange would be more suitable.

Anyway, read about regular expression in languages such as python, or use grep command together with awk to extract desired information.

Comment: Did you try solving this? What problems did you see?

Comment: I am trying in shell scripting only. I tried myself but I am able to print either first or second string only.

Comment: @Jaspreet.b87: Highlight your attempts and problems you faced in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all who helped me. I am able to get the result. Below is the command that I have used:

```
cat test.txt | grep "SEND" | sed 's/<\/ID>.*//g'|awk 'BEGIN {FS=" |>"} {print $2, $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this program:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{
    if($3 == "SEND") {
        gsub(/\..*/, "", $2)
        match($4, /<ID>([0-9]+)<\/ID>/, ary)
        printf "%s %s\n", $2, ary[1]
    }
}' input.txt
```

The `input.txt` is your example log, and the output of above program is :

```
10:10:10 SEND
10:10:11 SEND
```

Comment: While it is a good attempt, it does not answer the actual requirement of the author, please re-check your output with the author's expected output.

Comment: @Inian, Oh yes. I misread the question. Now I've fixed my question.